# Persist js user controls state

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, datepicker

My RIA application has a lot js UI controls (almost all of their is jQuery UI parts like datepicker, dialog, jqgrid). So then user works with some controls on one page and then go to another page and then clicks back all page components has initial state (textboxes are empty, grids are empty and so on). So how can I persist UI controls state and then restoring it between pages? It seems I need some like JS serialization/deserialization methods storing serialized data in user server session. How can I do it with minimal costs? How do you guys it in your projects? Any thougs, links, posts will be very appreciated. Thank you guys in advance!

P.S. My project is ASP .NET MVC3

---

### EDIT

Just now I remember about memnto design pattern. Could anyone of you advice me something related to this idea?
Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know what browser your users are on, or is this for general internet?

Comment: Is for general internet. More browser supporting is better.

Comment: then you're probably going to have to use cookies to store the data (unless you have server side options). store.js can work as well

Comment: @Sinetheta Thanks! What is the way I should use store.js?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot HTTP is stateless. Design a proper REST API then consume it. That or use winforms, it tends to do this horrible stateful HTTP nonsense for you. Just use the viewstate ;)

Comment: Yes, I know that HTTP is stateless protocol unless I didn't ask this question here :) Also there's no ability to use viewstate, 'cause all elements are some kind of jQuery plugins with a lot javascript logic in it. Thanks for your response!

Comment: The use of Viewstate have nothing to do with you using or not JQuery UI "addins". All you have to do is use server-side controls instead.
Not that for this you have to use the control client-side name, something like: $('#<%= MyDateTextbox.ClientID %>').datepicker();

This way you can apply JQuery UI on server-side controls and take advantage of the Viewstate restoring the controls value on back-button navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this as a comment of your question but I'm putting it as an answer as it might be the only way to do this without having to "hack" it with some sort of side plugins.

The use of Viewstate have nothing to do with you using or not JQuery UI "addins". All you have to do is use server-side controls instead.

Note that for this you have to use the control client-side name, something like:

```
$('#<%= MyDateTextbox.ClientID %>').datepicker();
```

This way you can apply JQuery UI on server-side controls and take advantage of the Viewstate restoring the controls value on back-button navigation.

Comment: Sorry mate, I haven't noticed you're using MVC 'till just now...
MVC is cool but takes more than it actually gives to developers (this is my honest opinion) and in this case it took you the Viewstate :)

Comment: I think that depends on what your priorities are. MVC gives you more control over the markup, allows you to use better SoC (a must for TDD and great for reusability -- ie: DataAnnotations), routing is a breeze, better control over AJAX (don't have to use WebMethods and hijack JavaScript plugins for them to work) and ... guess what... web forms pages, controls, etc. work in MVC projects because MVC is just a couple of libraries and references. You can use both in the same project if you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using Persist-JS ([Persist-JS on GitHub](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js)), jQuery (which you are using already) and json.js ([JSON-js on GitHub](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)) .
Something like this:

```
var store;
//Restore form data
$(function() {
    store = new Persist.Store('My Page Store');
    var formDataStr = store.get('formdata');
    if (formDataStr !== null) {
        var formData = eval('(' + formDataStr + ')');
        if (formData.hasData) {
            $(':input').each(function() {
                if (this.name != undefined && this.name != "") {
                    if (formData[this.name] != undefined) {
                        $(this).val(formData[this.name].value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and...

```
//Persist form data
$(window).unload(function() {
    var formData = {};
    $(':input').each(function() {
        if (this.name != undefined && this.name != "") {
            formData[this.name] = {};
            formData[this.name].value = $(this).val();
        }
    });
    formData.hasData = true;
    store.set('formdata', JSON.stringify(formData));
});
```

In other words, loop through all the inputs on the page, store their value (`$.val()`), create a JSON object and persist it for these values. When restoring the form, simply do the opposite -- loop through the inputs and grab the properties off of the JSON object by name `formData[name]`. There's some defensive stuff in there (ie: check for persisted object to be null, which is how persist-js works).