# Saving and recalling state of elements

Tags: javascript

I have a part of a form displayed in a jquery-ui dialog in which the user can change some settings. The settings are weighing factors for different items, and are displayed in two jqGrids "Not adjusted" (showing default values) and "Adjusted" (showing new values). The dialog is now to be given a "Cancel"-button, which should revert all settings back to the latest saved values. I'm having trouble deciding how to do this.

The user could potentially open this dialog several times before acually committing to the server, so I need to keep the state in the session somehow. Is there some javascript library which can save the state of an element along with it's children and then recall it? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you arn't using HTML5 I don't think you have any other option than to to save the data to a cookie or if you have a backing webservice you can send data to and collect from.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question similar to this one here:

[Persist JS User Controls State](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424544/76840)

If you're using a jQuery UI dialog, just change the code there to restore/persist before and after the dialog is shown/hidden.
I notice you say you are using jqGrid(s) -- this will store the element values but you may need some extra plumbing if the grids are using paging/AJAX/etc. (ie: set the grid back to the given page -- which can be stored in the same manner)